# Rails 部分テンプレートでpathを変数に置き換える方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

indexから部分テンプレートを呼び出し、その部分テンプレートからも
さらに部分テンプレートを呼び出しております。

一番下の階層の_shared/tag_listで
prepque_origques_pathを指定しており、こちらを何かの変数に
置き換えることで、他のviewからも呼び出せるようにしたいのですが
うまくできません。

prepque_origques_pathをindexで指定し
_shared/origque_content→_shared/tag_listと
変数を渡していくのはどのように記述すれば良いでしょうか?

**index**

```
<% @origques.each do |origque| %>
　<%= render partial: "_shared/origque_content", locals: { origque_content: origque,
          　  origque_url:prepque_origque_path(origque.prepque.id,origque.id),
          　  origque_memo_url:prepque_origque_memos_path(origque_id: origque.id) } %>
<% end %>
```

**_shared/origque_content**

```
<%= render '_shared/tag_list', tag_list: origque_content.grammar_list %></div>
```

**_shared/tag_list**

```
<% tag_list.each do |tag| %>
     <%=link_to tag, **prepque_origques_path**(tag_name: tag,order:params[:order],column:params[:column]), class:"label label-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

下記のように記述してみましたが、エラーになってしまします。

```
<%= render '_shared/tag_list', tag_list: origque_content.grammar_list, path: prepque_origques_path %>
```

```
<%=link_to tag, path(tag_name:tag,order:params[:order]" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

以下のような感じでいかがでしょうか?

```
<%= render '_shared/tag_list', tag_list: origque_content.grammar_list, path: :prepque_origques_path %>
```

と

```
<%=link_to tag, send(path, tag_name: tag, order: params[:order]) %>
```

手元で試していないので、うまくいかなかったらすみません。

Ruby では、メソッドはオブジェクトではないので、そのまま引数として渡すことはできません。代わりにシンボルを渡します。
そして、シンボルをメソッド名と見なして呼び出すには、`send` を使います。

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render '_shared/tag_list', tag_list: origque_content.grammar_list, path: :prepque_origques_path %>
```

と

```
<%=link_to tag, send(path, tag_name: tag, order: params[:order]) %>
```

で渡すことができました。